# MVC Linq OrderBy not persisting in Razor View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

I have a partial view in my web project that is responsible for displaying items in a navigation menu. The navigation menu item models have a SortOrder property on them that is responsible for displaying in what order they appear. The default value for unsorted is 0. So, I need to order by any value greater than 0, then by the name of the menu items that are not sorted. The problem is that my linq query is not respecting my sort order. It is instead showing the items with sortorder values of 0 first. I am using MVC 4 with .Net framework target 4.5. Thanks for any input.

Below is my code:

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.Item>
@helper ShowItems(List<Models.Item> items)
{
<ul>
    @foreach(var item in items)
    {
        <li>
            @item.DisplayName
            @if(Model.Any(x => x.ParentId == item.Id))
            {
                @ShowItem(Model.Where(x => x.ParentId == item.Id).OrderBy(x => x.SortOrder.Value > 0).ThenBy(y => y.DisplayName).ToList())
            }
        </li>
    }
</ul>
}
@ShowItems(Model.Where(x => !x.ParentId.HasValue || x.ParentId.Value == 0).OrderBy(x => x.SortOrder.Value > 0).ThenBy(y => y.DisplayName).ToList());
```

Comment: Do you need the non-zero SortOrder values in ascending order?

Comment: Yes. I failed to mention that detail. My apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OrderBy takes in an expression whose value is evaluated, and then ordered by the resulting value.   So in your case x => x.SortOrder.Value > 0 is a boolean evaluation - resulting in true of false.   I believe that equates to 0 or 1, so when sorted, your false's will come before your trues. Anything with SortOrder.Value == 0 will show up first. 
  You're comparing apples to oranges (booleans, and integers)

Try mapping oranges to apples like this:

```
OrderBy(x => x.SortOrder.Value > 0 ? 0 : 1).ThenBy(...);
```

Now you're sorting by integers, then by integers, instead of booleans, then integers.

Comment: Gahh. You are correct, Adam. Thanks! It's been a long day.

Answer (score 0):

use OrderByDescending  and order by x.SortOrder.Value

```
@ShowItems(Model.Where(x => !x.ParentId.HasValue || x.ParentId.Value == 0)
.OrderByDescending(x => x.SortOrder.Value)
.ThenBy(y => y.DisplayName).ToList());
```

Comment: Adam had the answer I was looking for. I thought I had mentioned but it doesn't seem I was specific enough that I was looking for my ordering to be ascending for any value greater than 0 first (Ex: 1,2,3,0,0).

Answer (score 0):

This will give you your list in ascending order by the `SortOrder` field with the exception that zeroes are at the end:

```
OrderBy(x => x.SortOrder.Value == 0 ? Int32.MaxValue : x.SortOrder.Value)
```